# bash string comparison fails

Tags: bash

I have a variable that stores the output of netcat

```
var=$(echo "flush_all" | nc localhost 111)
echo $var # outputs "OK"
if test "$var" != "OK"; then
    echo "failed"
    exit
fi
```

it outputs that it passed but when I want to programmatically check it is true, it fails. What is wrong with my comparison?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that the variable contains a carriage return from the command substitution.  You have a couple of options.  Ensure that the string starts with `OK`:

```
if [[ "$var" == "OK"* ]]; then
```

or, strip the CR during the variable assignment:

```
var=$(echo "flush_all" | nc localhost 111 | tr -d '\r')
```

---

You could use `od` to figure what a variable contains.  In the example below, the variable `var` contains `OK\r` which would appear as `OK` when trying to `echo` the variable.

```
$ echo "$var" | od -x
0000000 4b4f 0a0d
0000004
$ echo OK | od -x
0000000 4b4f 000a
0000003
```

Comment: CARRIAGE RETURN! I tried every delimeter but carriage return, thank you! that worked.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on 
    od
that will come in useful in the near future

Comment: It's even easier to spot a hidden carriage return if you use 'od -c', a bit more human friendly to read :)